# Is it possible to hook accesses in c++?

Tags: c++

For example, let's say I have a variable I want to protect from races, and when any kind of access occurs, it locks, accesses it, and unlocks(I know atomics exist but this is just an example).

Another example would be lazy-loading: everytime an access happens I want it to load if it's not already loaded.

I know it's possible to create a class with a function to call everytime I want to access it, like so:

```
template<typename T> class protected_data
{
    private:
    T data;
    std::mutex lock;
    public:
    T access()
    {
        T temp_data;
        lock.lock();
        temp_data = data;
        lock.unlock();
        return temp_data;
    }
};
```

But is it possible to do this with, let's say `(object == something)` instead of `(object.access() == something)`, since that would be clunky and easy to miss?

Comment: Are you aware that `operator==()` can be overloaded for `protected_data`? Btw. instead of calling `lock()` and `unlock`, you may have a look at [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) - the safer alternative.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `access` function should use `std::unique_lock` to lock the mutex: `T access() { std::unique_lock locker(lock); return temp_data; }` That way you don't have to do that dance to copy the value before you unlock the lock; the destructor for `unique_lock` will unlock the lock after the return value has been copied out. And it's exception-safe; as it's currently written, if `temp_data = data;` throws an exception the lock won't be unlocked, and nobody will know who's responsible.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload `operator ==` ([see it online](https://godbolt.org/z/qjWs6acYT))

```
template <typename T>
class protected_data;

template <typename T>
bool operator== (const protected_data<T>&, const T&);

template<typename T> 
class protected_data
{
public:
    protected_data(T data): data{std::move(data)} {}

private:
    friend bool operator== <>(const protected_data&, const T&);

    mutable std::mutex lock; // mutexes are often mutable, to allow passing by const&
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator== (const protected_data<T>& myAtomic, const T& other)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l {myAtomic.lock};
    return myAtomic.data == other; // beware, using .access() would lock mutex twice
}

// before C++20 you may also need reverse operator to make it symmetric
// template <typename T>
// bool operator== (const T& other, const protected_data<T>& atomic)
// {
//     return atomic == other;
// }
```

Note that you cannot make it work with `object.access() == something`, because that would require caller to lock the mutex somehow (unless you are fine with returning a copy and comparing against that copy without active lock).